# Threading in MonoTouch with webrequest and uialertview

Tags: iphone, ios, multithreading, xamarin.ios, monodevelop

I access a website and retrieve some data using `HttpWebRequest` and I need a `UIAlertView` with a `UIActivityIndicatorView` to display while it retrieves said data.  However, it just dims the screen and doesn't show the alert until it's too late.  I've read other threading related questions here and can't figure out how to resolve this.  I tried using ThreadPool, InvokeOnMainThread, Tasks, all of which have not worked.

EDIT:

```
HttpWebRequest url = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create ("maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/search/..); 

HttpWebResponse webResp = (HttpWebResponse)url.GetResponse (); JsonValue jVal = 

JsonObject.Load (webResp.GetResponseStream ()); 

JsonObject jObj = (JsonObject)jVal;
```

I have the above code, if it will properly format for me, how would I convert that to use WebClient? Can you still get JSON and such from it?

Comment: Can you post your current code that is not working?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's often a lot easier (and less error prone) to use `WebClient` and one of it's `*Async` methods than using `HttpWebRequest`.

Here's an example to download and show a small image.

```
WebClient client = new WebClient ();
var wait = new UIActivityIndicatorView (View.Bounds);
client.DownloadDataCompleted += (object sender, DownloadDataCompletedEventArgs e) => {
    byte[] result = e.Result;
    if (result != null) {
        NSData data = NSData.FromArray (e.Result);
        UIImage img = UIImage.LoadFromData (data);
        InvokeOnMainThread (delegate {
            ShowImage (img);
            wait.StopAnimating ();
        });
    }
};
wait.StartAnimating ();
client.DownloadDataAsync (new Uri (url));
```

**EDIT (for updated question)**

For streams you can use [`WebClient.OpenReadAsync`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/ms144211%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) and the [`OpenReadCompleted`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/system.net.webclient.openreadcompleted%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) event.

Comment: sorry, I attempted to ask the comment as an edit to my original question.  I'm quite the stack and monotouch novice.